# Can i change facebook account kit UI to my own edittexts and buttons and add more buttons on activity

Tags: facebook, account-kit

simply i want to add more buttons and use my own editTexts to get number and to change background theme as well.
any solution will be apperitiated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, AccountKit UI is locked due to legal reasons regarding having a specific disclaimer visible on the screen at all times when sending SMS notifications.

The only customization you can do is to use AdvancedUIManager and insert your own fragments on header, body and footer positions on the UI.

docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing/#advanced